# Workflows not being started when app deployed to another computer

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4.5

I have a console-app hosted workflow which runs fine on my PC, both under VS 2012 and as an EXE. It starts workflows in response to a Web Services call.

When deployed to another pc, the console app starts ok, doesn't error, and waits for a call to its Web Service. I can 'see' the endpoint.

If I then call that Web Service, the client doesn't error, neither does the console app, but the workflow doesn't start. Nothing is written to the Event Log either.

Any ideas what is going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first check would be to make the console app display something when it receives the remote call so you can be sure the app really got the command.

Comment: Richard, That is exactly what it does ;-)

Comment: I tried several things, including changing the port number, and eventually it worked. Can't understand why I got no error, though....

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Port Number was the culprit.

I now allow end-user to change this, just in case...